# How to return DDL success in a plpgsql function?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, functions, dynamic-sql, ddl

I have hundreds tables in a Postgresql-11 DB, need to be droped.

In order to simplified my work, I coded a function as following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dropTable(
  IN tab_name information_schema.sql_identifier,
  OUT succ bool )
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' AS
$func$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s CASCADE;', tab_name );
  -- How to get the executing successfulness of above statement ?

  -- following line can NOT return a boolean result
  GET CURRENT DIAGNOSTICS msg = PG_CONTEXT;
END
$func$;
```

And then call it in a query like this:

```
SELECT dropTable("table_name")
FROM information_schema."tables"
WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
  AND "table_name" LIKE 'ticks\___0000'
ORDER BY "table_name";
```

It works indeed, but can **NOT** return a boolean result that indicates whether or not the drop action had been successfully executed.

Is there a way to do so?

Or I have to return a literal value i.e. `RETURN True;`?

Answer (score 1):

A `drop table` cannot return a failed status. The command was either executed or an error was raised. In the latter case, the execution of the function and the surrounding transaction are aborted unless you [trap the error](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING).

---

psql can do the trick:

```
SELECT format('drop table %I', table_name)
FROM information_schema."tables"
WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
  AND "table_name" LIKE 'ticks\___0000'
ORDER BY "table_name";
\gexec
```

the `\gexec` command will execute any SQL that was generated by the previous query.